# Travis CI: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to setup CI for https://github.com/amCap1712/pljava using Travis. But it fails with following log:

```
find pljava-packaging -name \*.jar | sudo xargs java -jar
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/gjt/cuspy/JarX has 
been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this 
version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

The complete build log and travis config is available at https://travis-ci.org/github/amCap1712/pljava/builds/661687014 . I am using OpenJDK9 for this build but it fails for OpenJDK14 as well.
How to fix the error ?